# Pass an object as parameter in PHP

Tags: php

In Java, I can pass an object straight in parameter

```
public int foo (Bar bar)
{
    ... call the methods from Bar class
}
```

So how can I do same thing with PHP. Thanks
This is my code:

```
class Photo
{
    private $id, $name, $description;
    public function Photo($id, $name, $description)
    {
        $this->id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->description = $description;
    }
}
class Photos
{
    private $id = 0;
    private $photos = array();

    private function add(Photo $photo)
    {
        array_push($this->photos, $photo);
    }
    public function addPhoto($name, $description)
    {
        add(new Photo(++$this->id, $name, $description));
    }
}
$photos = new Photos();
$photos->addPhoto('a', 'fsdfasd');
var_dump($photos); // blank
```

If I change the  function add

```
function add($name, $description)
{
    array_push($this->photos, new Photo(++$this->id, $name, $description));
}
```

It works pefectly. So What is wrong ?

Comment: Have you tried doing this?  If so, can we see the code?  What went wrong?  Did you get an error?  See also [the PHP manual on objects](http://php.net/language.types.object) and [function arguments](http://php.net/functions.arguments).

Comment: Exactly the same way.

Comment: *If I change the function add [...] It works pefectly. So What is wrong ?* That's on you to tell us. What do you expect to happen and what happens? Do you get any error message etc. From what I can see, you should be calling the function as `$this->add(...)` not just `add(...)`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You do it the exact same way, just with some syntax changes, of course:

```
public function foo(Bar $bar)
{
    // $bar->method()
}
```

Keep in mind that you can only [type hint](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php) for classes and arrays.