# Can you implicitly instaniate an object when passing as a a parameter?

Tags: php, methods, parameters, type-hinting

At the suggestion of those here, I am trying to learn oop php.

I found a site that shows a real world implementation, via a social media example, and I was reading through and followed through mostly.

However I came across, what may just be an alternate syntax, on [this page](http://www.codedodle.com/2015/03/social-network-friends-relationship.html).

My question is regarding what seems to be an object from one class, being passed as an parameter to a method of a different class.

I read through a few other stackoverflow questions of similar nature, but only [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9332596/pass-an-object-as-parameter-in-php) demonstrated a similar syntax but that only came up in the answering of another question, not discussing what I am asking about in particular (which is located in an answer).

To be clear, from the first linked page an excerpt of the code;

```
public function getFriend(Relationship $rel) {
    if ($rel->getUserOne()->getUserId() === $this->loggedInUser->getUserId()) {
      $friend = $rel->getUserTwo();
    } else {
      $friend = $rel->getUserOne();
    }
    
    return $friend;
  }
```

The method **getFriend** is from the **relation** class, and the parameter of that method **Relationship $rel** I believe is an instantiate of the **Relationship** class.

However there is no

```
$rel = new Relationship
```

anywhere. is this *passing an object by reference*?

I know this is a newbie question so thanks, and yes I did look through [objects and classes](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php) section of the manual, so if I am not looking at the right part of the manual and you can give me a pointer in the right direction, thanks also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you're referencing something called *type hinting* or *type declaration* of the function arguments:

http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration

Basically what this is doing, is it's requiring that the variable be of type `Relationship`. If you try to pass any other type of variable into this method, you'll get a fatal error (PHP 5) or an exception (PHP 7).

Comment: so even though {$rel} wasnt already an instantiation of a class, this works? is it because the object is already stored in memory?

Comment: or i believe you are right but could you elaborate on this a bit more?

Comment: The object $rel has to already be instantiated and be of type Relationship in order for it to be passed to this method. This DOES NOT instantiate anything. It simply days "all variables not of type Relationship, are not welcomed here".